# Firebase cloud functions chess game Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making a chess app which has a Firebase backend, i am using cloud firestore and cloud functions. basically i am using node 8 to avoid billing issues on cloud functions, i can call and trigger, but i can't wrap my head about how to make an action happen on another device instead of on my own.

After authenticating and logging in, the user gets into a lobby which is a tableViewController and there are shown only the users that are currently logged in.

What i want to achieve is by tapping on a certain row the user that got the tap on it gets an alert shown for him which states whether he accepts the challenge or he declines it. Based on that i proceed to the game or do something else.

The question is though how to make this alert trigger on the other user's device?

Also i've seen some posts that it can be done with snapshotListener on a document, but again i run into the problem of understanding how to trigger the alert on another device. If you've got some other good ideas please share!

Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think snapshot listeners are really the only way to go. You could use other Firebase services but those aren’t the right tools for the job. Consider creating a collection, maybe call it requests:

```
[requests]
    <userId-userId> (recipientUserId-initiatorUserId)
        initiator: string
        recipient: string
        date: date
```

Each user has a snapshot listener that listens to this collection where their own userId is equal to `recipient`. You can add a date field to sort the list by most recent, for example. When a user wants to challenge another user, all they need to do is create a document in this collection:

```
<userId-userId> (recipientUserId-initiatorUserId)
    initiator: myUserId
    recipient: theirUserId
    date: now
```

And the recipient's client will instantly see this document.

You could include dressing data in this document, like the initiator's display name or a path to their avatar. But this data may be stale by the time it's rendered so the alternative is to fetch the dressing data from the database using the userId. You could also auto-gen the document ID but if you configure it (like this), it can make operations like deleting simpler. You could also configure the userIds to be alphanumerical so only one request can exist between two users; but if they requested each other at the same time, one would overwrite the other and you'd have to handle that potential edge case. There are lots of things to consider but this is the starting point.

Comment: Thank alot, i've figured it out after i asked the question but the idea is a bit better then mine, not connected to my initial question, have you ever encountered a problem when you call db.collection(a).document(id).getDocuments and it just does not do anything? it does not show error, just nothing, even not getting into the closure but just exits the method?

Comment: You cannot `getDocuments` on a single document, you can only get document**s** from a collection. Conversely, you can't `getDocument` from a collection, only on a document.

Comment: sorry it was a typo in my questions, i do db.collection(a).document(id).getDocument with no s in the end in my code that does nothing, no error just not going into the closure.